# Not able to add new column in infragistics WebHierarchicalDataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics

I am trying to add new column whose value will be computed from code behind and display it on `WebHierarchicalDataGrid` as separate column. I added below code :

**Aspx page :**

```
 <ig:TemplateDataField Key="htmllink">
     <Header Text="HtmlLink" CssClass="grey bold" />
 </ig:TemplateDataField>
```

Problem is I am not able to understand how to add it in code behind and on which event to compute its value. I tried doing it on `onrowislanddatabinding`, but couldnt do so in below event.

```
 protected void WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_RowIslandDataBinding(object sender, RowIslandEventArgs e)
{


  //e.RowIsland.Columns["htmllink"] = value 1 + value 2.

}
```

I am not sure what needs to be done as I am new to infragistics.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataBinder.Eval()` method direclty in the markup to calculate the value for the field. You can see example here: https://www.infragistics.com/samples/aspnet/data-grid/alternating-row-templates
Otherwise, the InitializeRow event is best to calclulate value.